# Подскажите как такие бордеры сверстать?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите пожалуйста как такие бордеры сверстать? Пытался скопировать CSS но не получается никак...[тут ссылка на пример](http://demo2.oceanplazatheme.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать svg, как в примере ниже. Если интересно, то вот ссылка на codrops: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/03/a-collection-of-separator-styles/

```css
/* Big Triangle */
svg#bigTriangleColor {
 pointer-events: none;
}

#bigTriangleColor path {
 fill: #3498db;
 stroke: #3498db;
 stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

### Update #1

Второй способ с помощью JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function border_width() {
    var w = $(window).width() / 2;
    $('.header-border-bot').css('border-left-width', w);

    $('.header-border-bot').css('border-right-width', w);
  }

  $(window).on('load resize', function () {
    border_width();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header-border-bot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -29px;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid dashed;
  border-width: 30px 960px 0px;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-border-bot">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оказывается не совсем то что мне нужно) дело в том что у меня параллакс между секциями. Немогу добиться эффекта как тут - http://demo2.oceanplazatheme.com/

Comment: @pwnz22

Тогда так http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLwXWb. На том сайте работает по такому же принципу. 

Но что-то нестандартное будет сложно построить (придется манипулировать before и after).

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно) +адаптивность  есть)